# Сохранить mp3 файл с помощью php

Tags: php, файлы

Есть ссылка нужно скачать и сохранить файл, не подскажите как? Сначала курл, а потом fwrite?

Comment: Почему бы не попробовать?

Comment: Можете и http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php + http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

```
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $str = $singer.'_'.$name;
        $str = mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8');
        $str = $id.'_'.$str;
        $fp = fopen('../music/'.$str.'.mp3', 'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
```